# Open a command in a new window

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

Im trying to execute :YcmComplete GoToDefinition in a new window, but I can't figure out how to execute a vim command in a new window, any pointers?

When I use split that doesn't work because that is for splitting a window and opening a document, not executing the output of a jump command etc. to a new window.

essentially im binding it to a key so that when i do it, it opens in a new window, so i dont have to jump back and forth, then when i see it and get it, i can just c and be exactly where i was.

Comment: Specifically for YouCompleteMe there is an option for this, see `help g:ycm_goto_buffer_command`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you mean because you discarded the possibility of using `:split`... I would simply do like this:

```
:split|YcmComplete GoToDefinition
```

Then you can type <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> to go back to the window where you were (or <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to close the new window).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I seem to have a different `YouCompleteMe` version where `:YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration` seems to achieve a similar result. For some reason your solution did not work for me when I tried `:split|YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration` as is, but did work when I modified it some more to `:split<CR> :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>`.